# Loss when transfering electrial energy

Tags: electricity, electrons, electrical-resistance

Let's say we want to transfer a given amount of electrical energy $E$.
We could do this with a voltage of $100\,\rm{V}$, but it's better to transform 
the voltage to $1000\,\rm{V}$, hence the loss of enery is now one hundreth 
of the orginal loss of energy, because we calculate the loss of energy by
$R\,I^2$, where $R$ is the resistance of the wire and the current drops 
to one tenth of original current if we transfer the voltage.
But what reasons can we give for the drop of the loss of energy on the basis 
of the electrons? With other words: why is it so much better to have one 
electron to transfer an energy of $100\,E_0$ instead of 100 electrons each trasfering 
an energy of $E_0$?

Comment: The electrons aren't transporting energy, at all. The energy transport is done entirely by the electromagnetic field around the wire. What the wire does is to provide suitable boundary condition so that the potential at one end of the wire can be reproduced at the other end with relatively low losses.

Comment: Okay, but im still searching for an explantion on the level of atoms, or if you want on the basis of the expanding electro-magnetic field, why he have less loss with higher voltage and lower current.

Comment: More electrons are being accelerated in a higher electric field (voltage drop along the cable), there are more collisions and that causes the $I^2R$ law.

Answer (score 0):

At atomic level, electrons flow through a conductor at [drift velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drift_velocity). While flowing through the atomic lattice, charge carriers can collide with ions in the conductor, resulting in charge carriers moving more randomly. This random motion corresponds to the thermal energy emanated from the conductor while a current is flowing inside it and this energy is said to be lost.

The reason why high voltage transmission lines prevent high levels of energy loss is that high voltage and less current while maintaining certain power level(since $P=VI$) means electric field due to the current source is accelerating less charge carriers per unit time but each charge carrier has higher electrostatic potential energy.(as you figured) Consequently, less charge carriers mean there are less number of interactions(collisions) between the charge carriers and the ions in the lattice; and therefore less loss of energy.(As CuriousOne pointed out.)